# Using a while loop as a wait in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have done this in C/C++ before where I have a while loop that acts as a wait holding the program up until the condition is broken. In Python I am trying to do the same with `while(GPIO.input(24) != 0):` and its says that it is expecting an indent. Is there anyway to get the script to hang on this statement until the condition is broken?

Answer (score 19):

Do note that an empty while loop will tend to hog resources, so if you don't mind decreasing the time resolution, you can include a `sleep` statement:

```
while (GPIO.input(24) != 0):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

That uses less CPU cycles, while still checking the condition with reasonable frequency.

Answer (score 15):

In Python, you need to use the `pass` statement whenever you want an empty block.

```
while (GPIO.input(24) != 0):
    pass
```

Comment: One interesting thing I learnt today was that the `pass` statement can be used anywhere a non-op is syntactically necessary, not just in loops.

Comment: Exactly; that includes any part of `try`/`except`/`else`/`finally`, as another example.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `pass`, as such:

```
while(GPIO.input(24) != 0):
    pass
```

You might also consider a different approach:

```
while True:
    if GPIO.input(24) == 0: break
```

Whichever you think is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can't leave the colon `:` hanging so you must use a `pass` to complete the empty block. Another way to use a `while` in this way

```
 while True:
     if GPIO.input(24) == 0:
         break
```